# Python to Netezza JDBC Connection giving SQL .execute Error on Mac

Tags: python, database, macos, jdbc, netezza

So I am writing a Python script to retrieve the count of Netezza table DB. However, I am getting the following error. Please let me know how I can fix this.

```
  File "/Users/skulk00/PycharmProjects/NZ_RS_Validator/table_details_thread_pool.py", line 175, in <module>
    result = result_netezza_cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM STORE')
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

This is my connection code:

```
NETEZZA_JAR_LOC = os.path.join('/Users/skulk00/Connection Softwares/nzjdbc.jar')
NETEZZA_PP = ('username', 'password', 'xx.6.8.xx', 'dbname', 'netezza', 'org.netezza.Driver', '5480')

class Connector:
    """Create Database connection."""

    def __init__(self, db_name):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.all_db = {
            'netezza_pp': NETEZZA_PP,
            'netezza_prod': NETEZZA_PROD,
        }
        if self.db_name not in self.all_db:
            raise ValueError(f'Available database choices are {tuple(self.all_db.keys())}')

    def _get_cxn_string(self, user, password, host, dbname, dialect, driver, port):
        if 'netezza' in self.db_name:
            db_string = f'jdbc:{dialect}://{host}:{port}/{dbname}'
        return db_string

    def cursor(self):
        db_name = self.db_name
        db_creds = self.all_db[db_name]
        db_string = self._get_cxn_string(*db_creds)

        print(db_name)
        print(db_creds)
        print(db_string)

        if 'netezza' in db_name:
            cxn = jaydebeapi.connect('org.netezza.Driver', db_string, {'user': db_creds[0], 'password': db_creds[1]}, jars=NETEZZA_JAR_LOC)
        return cxn
```

This is my main function code:

```
result_netezza_connector = Connector('netezza_pp')
result_netezza_cursor = result_netezza_connector.cursor()
result = result_netezza_cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM STORE')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [Python native nzpy](https://github.com/ibm/nzpy) driver for python scripts' interaction with Netezza

```py
import nzpy

conn = nzpy.connect(user="...", password="...", host='...', 
                port=5480, database="...")

with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(...)
```

For more detailed examples, you can refer to [these samples](https://github.com/aniket-s-kulkarni/nz-samples/tree/main/nzpy)

---

Back to the JDBC question - The problem is you are returning a `jayedebeapi.Connection` from `Connector.cursor()` method, rather than a cursor.

```py
result_netezza_connector = Connector('netezza_pp')
with result_netezza_connector.cursor().cursor() as result_netezza_cursor:
    result_netezza_cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM STORE')
    print(result_netezza_cursor.fetchall())

# a better option to display is using pandas
import pandas
df = pandas.read_sql('SELECT COUNT(1) from STORE',
      result_netezza_connect)
df 
# will print tabular and you can use the dataframe for further
# processing
```

The `.cursor().cursor()` is confusing and I would recommend renaming the `Connection.cursor()` method to `Connection.connection()`. That would make it more readable -

```py
with result_netezza_connector.connection().cursor() as ...
```

---

Here's a minimal example of the same in a python notebook

[image: Here's a minimal example of the same in a python notebook]

Comment: Still getting the same error to the fix you provided. Technically, the line that you suggested 'result_netezza_connector.cursor() as result_netezza_cursor:' works the same way as my 'result_netezza_cursor = result_netezza_connector.cursor()'

Comment: You are right! thanks for the help but your correction code is wrong. Please do edit it.

Comment: @ShreyasKulkarni - right, it was a copy paste issue. I have edited the comment.